# Why does this neo4j query not finish?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The following doesn't finish

```
MATCH path = (start:A)-[*]->(end:A)
WHERE start.fen = 'abc'
WITH distinct path as distinct_path
WHERE length(distinct_path) > 3
return distinct_path
LIMIT 10
```

But when removing the WHERE clause, it returns

```
MATCH path = (start:A)-[*]->(end:A)
WHERE start.fen = 'abc'
WITH distinct path as distinct_path
return distinct_path
LIMIT 10
```

What about the WHERE clause makes it not finish?

Answer (score 0):

Both queries have a `LIMIT 10`, but the second query is not qualified by any `WHERE` clause, so it can simply return you the first 10 it finds.

It just finds 10 and stops.

The first query, with the additional `WHERE`, means your returned 10 *must* have a path length > 3, which means it must traverse all the shorter paths and discard them, keeping track in memory of the paths it has tried. You are only looking for the longer paths. So it is simply more computation effort. And maybe more computation effort than we have patience for waiting.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77395391/2258090) by Stewart correctly answers your question as to why the `WHERE` changes the performance.

But to actually improve the performance of your first query, move the criteria into the lower bound for the length of paths matched:

```
MATCH path = (start:A)-[*4..]->(end:A)
WHERE start.fen = 'abc'
WITH DISTINCT path AS distinct_path
RETURN distinct_path
LIMIT 10
```